# Attaching Web Version to google analytics web tracking

Tags: google-analytics

I'm using google analytics to track information about my website and I want to attach a web version to all of the reports just as a app version is attached to the reports in an android or ios app.

Here's how I'm using it:

```
(function (i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
                i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r;
                i[r] = i[r] || function () {
                            (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)
                        }, i[r].l = 1 * new Date();
                a = s.createElement(o),
                        m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];
                a.async = 1;
                a.src = g;
                m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)
            })(window, document, 'script', '//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');

            ga(
                    'create',
                    'UA-XXXXXX-1',
                    'auto'
            );

            ga('send', 'pageview');
```

Is that possible?

Comment: Sure, look for "Google Analytics custom dimension" - this is pretty well documented.

Comment: Ok so I added `ga('set', 'dimension1', '1.1');` but how can I see it in google analytics?